# Why is my python installation not working properly?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

http://pastebin.com/BJiXC022

At first my python is working just fine with tkinter. When I change the working directory, it somehow stops working then. It even manages to refer the tkinter.py file in that directory even when I never even typed the name of the file there. I just wanted to import tkinter. My tkinter.py file is also not working even though it is almost exactly the same as the first 10 lines. How do I fix this problem? I reinstalled os and python yesterday, I am running OS X 10.10.3 and the newest Python 3.4.3. Here's tkinter.py:

http://pastebin.com/VBHqFGLZ

Comment: don't call yur file `tkinter.py`. it shadows the `tkinter` module.

Comment: One suggestion: Your file appears to be called `tkinter.py`. In your file you `import tkinter`. What do you think happens then? Edit: I See @mata beat me to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file named `tkinter.py` in `/Users/nikolas/Documents/Python/tkinter.py`. Changing to that directory and importing `tkinter` will import the local file, not the one from your Python installation. You see the error because your `tkinter.py` file does not provide `Tk`.

The solution is to rename your file to something other than `tkinter.py`.

Comment: Thank you! It still didn't work but I had some old tinter.pyc or something like that in the same folder and after the deletion of that everything works.

Comment: You mean `tkinter.pyc`? You need to be clear about the file names as this is probably the source of the problem in this case.

Comment: Yes tkinter, it was a typo. Still learning this new keyboard.